# Will an ANR dialog show up in production for users? Do phones matter, what on Android Automotive?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-anr-dialog, android-automotive, automotive

the main question I'm asking is:

- Does Google prevent ANR dialogs to show up on the customer side when my app is released?
- Do manufacturers disable ANR dialogs at some point on the customers side (I think I remember Huawei / Honor was doing something like that)
- If not, is there a way to prevent ANR dialogs on the customer side (production app)?
- Does anyone know what happens with Android Automotive? Is it possible to show ANRs there?

Thanks a lot for your feedback,
really appreciate your feedback and help!

Comment: afaik starting some OS version Android stopped showing crash/ANR dialogs, thats not manufacturer decision.. but still may be, some of them disabled these dialogs earlier than in "official release" and some may turned them on in later... personally I haven't seen these dialogs for long time... (and question about Automotive is out of scope and to broad)

Comment: Hey @snachmsm, thanks a lot for your feedback! I feel the same (didn't see them for a long time as a user) but never read or heard of any confirmation / official news in that area. That's why I'm asking. I'm just searching for some proof 

Comment: check out [THIS](https://www.xda-developers.com/android-p-app-not-responding-crash-dialogue/) article as a hook for further research :) (note screenshot in there and option "Always show crash dialog", disabled)

Comment: Thanks @snachmsm. That's what I was searching! Thanks a lot for the link and support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

answering officially for question: [starting Android P system won't show ANR dialog](https://www.xda-developers.com/android-p-app-not-responding-crash-dialogue/), well, by default. There are some options in Developer options for bringing crash/ANR dialogs back and you never know when some Manufacturer turn these on by default (I very doubt for common devices/smartphones, but some "special case" units or "modded" OS versions, which Android Automotive kind-of is, are possible to have such flag turned on)